# Solve equation $X^r=Id$ in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb F_q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-groups

Let $q$ be an odd prime power. Solve equation $X^r=Id$ in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb F_q)$ where $r$  divides

$$|\operatorname{SL}_n (\Bbb F_q)| = \frac{1}{q-1} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^i)$$

A solution $X$ should be diagonalizable. Hence the eigenvalues of $X=PDP^{-1}$ should be all $r$-th roots of unity lying on the diagonal matrix D. I don't know how to proceed from here, How can we fully describe $P$ and therefore describe a solution $X$.

### Edit

My statement above about the fact that solutions should be diagonalisable is false. I had also in mind a related question

- Is it possible to link the number of solutions to the number $r$?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why should a solution be diagonalizable?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to find diagonalisable elements of order dividing $r$ or are you asserting that elements of order dividing $r$ are diagonalisable? [The latter could scarcely be more false.] There is also the possible ambiguity about "diagonalisable" - do you mean in $\mathbb{F}_q$ or are extension fields allowed?

Comment: I am sorry I was mistaken, It is true for  $r=2$ that $X$ is diagonalizable (we can look at the Jordan normal form which can only be a diagonal matrix) and the solutions of $X^2=Id$ are only $\pm Id$. But it is not true for a general $r\ge3$ that $X$ is diagonalizable. My apologies, should I delete this statement from the questions? By diagonalizable I actually meant in $\Bbb F_q$ only.

Comment: I think you are asking a difficult question. Look at this, for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272440/maximal-order-of-elements-in-sln-q